Using of global URLs in XSLT applications
I'm trying to update a large XSL script. The beginning of the script is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
   Copyright (c) 2002 Douglas Gregor <doug.gregor -at- gmail.com>

   Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
   (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
   http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
  -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/common/common.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="reference.xsl"/>

The issue I'm concerned about is the referencing of files on the net via HTTP protocol. In this example there are xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" and <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/common/common.xsl"/>.
I see this everywhere. But it looks like a bad idea to me.  Specifically, what happens when www.w3.org disappears or gets repurposed? Same for docbook.sourceforge.net. My code would then fail with no obvious way to fix it.
Is this code not a problem? If not why not? Or should I download the referred files to my local system and import from there? I haven't seen this question addressed anywhere and I can't help but think I'm missing something obvious. What am I missing here?

The URLs after xmlns:*= are not loaded, they only serve as namespace identifiers. Regarding the xsl:import statement, you have a point, if you think your local system will last longer than sourceforge.net.

Or if you need to run the transformation even if there is no Internet connection.

You can use XML Catalogs for this. See https://xmlcatalogs.org/ and [tag:xmlcatalog].

Namespace URI are just to have a globally distinct names/namespaces, no XSLT processor will try to load anything from http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform to execute XSLT code. As for your import, I suggested you read up on catalogs before

You also could mirror the imported file yourself, although then you need to consider how you keep it updated, etc.
